# Calling with discord to write in a fileI have aa

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a script, a discord bot such that when I write !add --insert link here-- it would add text line of link in products.txt file, and !remove would remove existing one.
Problem happens when I try to add something, it sometimes adds multiple lines of the same thing. Such as !add www.google.com writes three lines of it, sometimes one.
Here's my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user: return
    author = message.author
    content = message.content
    channel = message.channel
    if "!add" in content:
        content = str(content)
        url = content.strip("!add")
        url = url.replace(" ", "")
        botmessage = "Added URL: " + url
        with open("products.txt", "a") as txtfile:
            txtfile.write(url+"\n")
        print(botmessage)
        await message.channel.send(botmessage)
    elif "!remove" in content:
        content = str(content)
        print(content)
        urls = content.split(" ")
        url = urls[1]
        print(url)
        txtfile = open("products.txt", "r")
        url_links = txtfile.readlines()
        txtfile.close()
        with open("products.txt", "w") as txt:
            for link in url_links:
                if url != link:
                    txt.write(link)
                else:
                    print("found it")
        botmessage = "Removed URL: " + url
        print("remove")
        await message.channel.send(botmessage)
```

Comment: Is there a possibility you are running multiple instances of your bot?

Comment: Have you narrowed down the problem, done any debugging?